# Why does the community seem to encourage technical cleverness over the actual answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes

First post on meta, so here goes nothing.

Earlier today, I answered the question linked below:

[Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{3x}{\sqrt{4-3x}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225899/evaluating-int-01-frac3x-sqrt4-3x-dx/3225910#comment6637577_3225910)

I believe it is a good question. The user had a specific concern, and expressed it in detail, with good-faith effort made to understand. It is perhaps an elementary concern, but a valid one.

Three answers were posted. Only one has received any upvotes (two) and in no way answers the question the user had, but merely presents a slick alternate approach.

To be clear, I have no problem at all with the upvoted answer or its poster, and I think it is good to have that easier solution there, but I feel as though it was upvoted for being clever, despite in no way answering the specific question the user had, while the other answers were ignored.

This seems to be a bit of a theme on MSE. It has happened to me before, and I see it in many other answer sections as a lurker as well. Am I grossly misunderstanding how this is all supposed to work? Perhaps I am simply wrong and my answer is lukewarm enough to deserve neither up or down votes?

Also, I do not necessarily care about getting votes for my own answer, so please don't think I do, but is there some essential element of a quality answer that I have missed here?

I hope all is in order. Feel free to school me on "meta-quitte" if need be.

Comment: My opinions here: $\LaTeX$ is very visible, and maybe the actual question would have been answered if it was better highlighted, i.e. using box quotes >

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I agree with you. Still, that just sounds like people aren't really carefully reading.

Comment: In my opinion, you didn't understand what OP was after in Question 1, and thus didn't give OP what was needed. The answer by Viktor Glombik strikes me as being what OP wanted/needed.

Comment: For me *cleverness* means something other than standard procedure explained in several textbooks, but to each their own I suppose (and "standard" is a relative term here, with its meaning varying from one person to another). Your main issue, if I got it right, was recently discussed [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30076/11619).

Comment: @GerryMyerson See, perhaps it is all about perception. It seemed to me like that answer just retyped what the OP already had from in the answer, which he said he understood, but asked *where* the idea for the manipulation came from.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I remember that post. I thought "finally!" when it was posted, but then everyone reverted back to their old ways of upvoting such non-answers.

Comment: My answer to your question (though too short to be a proper answer) is because the community generally agrees that indirect answers to questions that suggest alternative approaches are perfectly fine and add value to the site. They may be less helpful to the OP, although they certainly can be, but even if they aren't, helping the OP is not the only purpose to the site.

Comment: A similar concern in here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30076/why-do-users-give-answers-using-alternative-method-when-im-asking-what-went-wro

Comment: There are a couple of things about technical cleverness, which is not entirely out of place - though I do think that sometimes more effort could be taken to help the person asking the question. There is a concept of abstract duplicate which reflects questions with the same mathematical content - what this does not capture is that different users have different issues with that content. On the other hand it is painful to see people struggling with inefficient methods, and people want to excite others with beautiful things they know. Coaching and mathematics both have their place, I think.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, I think I agree with you entirely. In my personal experience, the technical/clever insight comes later, but perhaps a better answer than any posted on that question would include both. Though, I admittedly did not include such things since the other answer already had it. I like that answer and upvoted it, but I do not think it answered the question as posed. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: Please do not use quote environments for emphasis. It’s very confusing and also could easily break compatibility with design changes, accessibility, etc.

Comment: Considering that it is clearly listed on the how to format column, I am unsure why it is not meant to be used @Wrzlprmft : https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5MZJ.png

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: It is meant to be used, but for quotes, i.e., reproducing a somebody else’s text or to encapsulate a statement that is referred to (e.g., like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1029272/65502)) – with other words: something that you could put into quotation marks (but usually won’t due to length). It is not meant to be used to highlight a part of the question as particularly important. This can be done using boldface or headers (depending on the situation).

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: [Pertinent meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23015/65502).

Comment: "In brief, the use of block quotes is fine if the thing in the quote is intended to be set off from the rest of the text. (It does not have to be a quote proper.)" - from the accepted answer @Wrzlprmft

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: See [my comment there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23015/is-using-blockquote-for-highlighting-problematic#comment130912_23018).

Comment: @jgon Isn't the primary and very worthwhile purpose of StackExchange sites for the more expert contributors to help OPs to learn? IMO the demonstrations of expertise, succinctness etc to gain approval/admiration from ones expert peers comes second. While it doesn't happen very often, to be blown off with a smart but impenetrable/unedifying reply can seem like pure arrogance - something of which we are, perhaps, all guilty at times...

Comment: @iSeeker I'm not sure how your reply is related to my comment. While the primary purpose *may* be to help the OPs learn, all I said was that answers with alternative approaches to a problem add value to questions in the view of the community, which has nothing to do with what the primary purpose of the site is. Moreover, I never said that answers whose primary purpose is to impress others add value. In fact, I think an answer that doesn't explain anything doesn't add value at all.

Comment: @iSeeker (continued) That's one of my problems with this question, is that it seems to misattribute motives to people, which I tried to get at in my original comment. It suggests that the people who wrote the "slick" answers weren't trying to help the OP because they didn't directly answer the OPs question, and it suggests that the community values those answers more than direct answers to the question because of an impulse to support the fancier or smarter answer over the answer to the question asked.

Comment: @iSeeker (continued) In reality, there are many good reasons to write and support alternative answers that don't directly answer the question asked. Perhaps the most important of which is that we want the question and answers to have value to people who are not the OP, i.e., to future searchers and readers. Otherwise, we might as well delete the question and answer if it won't help anyone else.

Comment: @iSeeker (continued) Finally, to reply to your comment on receiving an impenetrable reply. Certainly I can understand that that could feel like pure arrogance, but I think there are many reasons for why that could be the case, which do not suppose that the answerer didn't intend to be helpful. One possible reason is that the answerer didn't understand the OPs level or context properly and answered at a higher level of abstraction, whether this is due to a lack of context in the question or expert blindness, or even unfamiliarity with a specific field, this is not a desire to show off.

Comment: @jgon Thank you for your comprehensive reply. This thread concerns a topic of particular interest to me, and I picked on your reply more as a route in to making my points than to contradict you. While I agree that additional and peripheral answers add value, I read your comment as indicating that answering the OP is no more important than indirect answers. It seems to me to be good manners to at least acknowledge the OP, even if only to say something like “This doesn’t answer your question but it might be of interest to others”. (continued...)

Comment: @jgon (continuation) ...But then again, one sometimes gets flamed as off-topic for not answering the OP. While I’ve sometimes been annoyed by clever answers that seem to ignore the OP’s request for aid in understanding, I wasn’t accusing you of saying this, rather I was using the comment to make the point generally. I’m in complete agreement that “an answer that doesn't explain anything doesn't add value at all”, and also with your later continuations replying to mine. Thank you.

Comment: @iSeeker you raise precisely my concerns. why is there no consistency? the difference is clearly occurring at the distinction between a feeling of intellectual superiority and one of obviousness. it is either ok or not, and while i accept there will be different views on this, i expect the major players in the community to act consistently and in accordance with precedent.