# Quoted paragraph gets white

Tags: discussion

Recently, I found that when I use `>` to quote a paragraph, the color is now white or some kind of silver. Personally, I think that the yellow is more ease to the eyes.

Could you please explain why the color has changed? Is there any way to restore the old yellow color?

Comment: Several months ago, site managers have tried to enforce a very politically correct policy concerning gender pronouns, which only served to enrage their user base. As such, they are now trying to enforce a highly [controversial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewashing_in_film) policy with regards to background colors.

Comment: It still looks fine on mobile devices, hopefully they will not "fix" it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is intended and there is no way to revert.  For more information and discussion about the matter, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes).

A quick summary of the motivation, found in the aforementioned post:

> We’re making a few changes to blockquotes soon. Historically, we had a bit of feedback that the yellow backgrounds were overpowering, reducing the contrast of the quote itself. The yellow border also lacks contrast with the background. Others have indicated that there should be more visible differences between block quotes and spoilers and between code and quotes.
>
> These yellows also compete with theming in our communities, especially those with backgrounds that aren’t perfectly white like English Language & Usage and Role-Playing Games.
>
> We’re proposing we switch to a single gray bar in our blockquotes. This should fix those theming issues and make it easier to distinguish between quotes, spoilers and code.
>
> This will also improve blockquote nesting, since our current nesting is a mess because the darker yellow bar is barely noticeable on the paler yellow background.

Comment: +1 Regardless of whether one likes it or not (personally I don't), this is the right answer.

Comment: And these announcements are made in meta where many of us have no reputation for downvoting. Annoying.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you could ask/answer to earn 24 points so that you could downvote

Comment: @user486983: fair enough, but it means that unless I have something meaningful to say, either I have to farm reputation, or I have no voice in situations like this (when I do have meaningful reputation is several SE sites).

Comment: @MartinArgerami well.. then make a choice. I am sure you have meaningful things to say. For example, I have earned ~200 points by just asking 4 questions

Comment: @MartinArgerami Actually, they lowered the threshold to downvote on Meta.SE to avoid this issue (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286150/663816), so even with 101 reputation you can downvote all questions you want (but only two answers, since it cost rep). (After writing this I realised you have 99 rep on Meta.SE, so   I guess you knew this already...)

Comment: In mobile site it is still yellow. Now people will have to stop abusing the use of blockquotes... quid warned us all this could happen

Comment: @PaulPlummer Could you please tell more? When and what did quid tell about it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე there have been questions in the past about the very frequent misuse of blockquotes to emphasize something and quid has written some answers on it. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23018/29123) for example.